# Other Location option not working in Linux

Tags: filesystems, kali-linux, hard-disk

I dual booted my Windows 8.1with Kali Linux Dual-Booted (secondary). Usually, I am able to access my other partitions of HDDs while working on Linux. I only need to make sure that my Windows is complete shutdown (This makes sure disks are not hibernated)

> shutdown /s /t 0

But, now the option of Other Location in Linux is not working, and is not showing anything. I tried to look for solutions and the best thing I was able to [find](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?34660-Kali-Linux-isn-t-able-to-display-what-s-in-quot-Other-Locations-quot) was to install another file explorer, like dolphin.
Is there any way I can fix this thing without installing anything extra?

Comment: Are your other partitions mounted?

Comment: Not yet... File Explorer shows the option to mount my disks after I click on Other Locations. Now, the other location option is not showing anything. @Peschke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons due to which one can’t access all the drives present in a Linux system, especially in the case of dual boot. Normally if you are not seeing any kind of error, then the first thing you should check is whether your file explorer is working fine.
I ran the following commands in my terminal

> apt-get update
>   apt-get install file-roller
>   apt-get install nautilus

The second command installs file-roller which is simply an archive manager for GNOME (will work for Kali) environment. For more information on filer-roller, you can visit this [link](http://fileroller.sourceforge.net/features.html).
Nautilus is a graphical file manager which visually displays system and user files. You can read more about nautilus [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/s1-desktop-nautilus.html).

Answer (score 0):

Today same thing happen with me, and like you i have searched for the solution. But nothing is working in my case. So i start doing R & D Myself. i found two solution, by which you do not have to install any app or software for that.

1 - Select Tweak Tool Option from the Main Menu.
2 - Select Extension Option from the Left hand side of Tweak Tool Menu.
3 - Scroll down & Select Removable Drive Menu, Now Turn it On.
Now You can see Right hand side on the top One Drive option is Appeared.
when You Click on that You will found All your Drives Options there.
For More Info, You can see Screen-shots here -
[image]
[image]

Comment: It works when you have problems with mounting. In my case, the file browser gets corrupted somehow or was malfunctioning.

Comment: You say you found "two solution" [sic].  Can you clarify what they are? I see a list with 3½ steps, and two screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is definitely working.

I tried another simple solution to explore files and other location

1. Simply go home directory and open it
2. from file explorer click on sidebar and check it
3. it will work correctly.

for more info follow the following pictures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: (1a) There are four answers to this question — yours and three others — and they are presented to different people in different orders at different times.  So “The above solution” is ambiguous.  If you need to refer to another answer from your answer, refer to it by name and link.  (1b) But, in general, answers shouldn’t comment on other answers unless they are closely related.  I see no need for the first sentence of your post.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) “A picture is worth a thousand words.”   Images can be a great way to illustrate text.   But yours aren’t.   A picture of your home directory doesn’t *clarify* your instruction to “go home directory and open it.”   And your second image has so much clutter in it, I have no idea what information we’re supposed to get from it.

Answer (score -1):

The Second Solution is You can Bookmarked Your Drives Just Above the "Other Location" Option, I will Show You -

1 - Go to the Menu & type "Disks".
2 - Select Option Disks, Now You can See All Your Drives Partitions there.
3 - Now Select Your Drive, and Click on "play" icon, if it is already mounted then it show "stop" icon, don't click on that.
4 - When you click on "play" it will mounted your drives, you can see Contents option just below the partition  with Mounted at Options.
5 - Click on the link given by Mounted At option, it will open your drive.
6 - When it will open You can see at top left hand side drive name is there.
7 - Drag that name option and take it to above the other location.
8 - When You try to place it there, You can see New Bookmark Option will be highlighted.
9 - Just place it there & You will get Your Drive Options present there.
10 - Just make sure that auto mount option is on.

For more info you can see Scree-shots here -

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The directory location going to have a stage rout by default, but it works. You can change the "Mount Point" to have a simpler expression. Default Ex.: "/mnt/473FEEF3378EF"   -->  "drive1"

Comment: Also you may need to restart the system to finalize the renaming of the mount.